# How to enforce dependency rules in javascript/typescript/webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Simply put, I need a way to restrict dependencies, much like you would with different projects (libraries) in java/c#. Friend or internal access modifiers if you will.

I'm toying with some ideas to do that (like creating loaders to ensure only allowed dependencies are used), but I can't imagine it hasn't been done before.

Of course, I'm talking about more than class encapsulation. My way right now would be to make modules only able to directly reference modules under their own folder structure or index files of other modules.

Is this really something no one ever needed?

Comment: *Is this really something no one ever needed?* I don't think anybody will have done this, at least not in a generic way. I would never think to impose this restriction programatically.

Comment: Write some comments in the modules saying how and where they should be used.

Answer (score 3):

You can use dependency cruiser to validate code base against your own rules based on regex literals. You can use it as part of your CI chain.

https://github.com/sverweij/dependency-cruiser

Answer (score 1):

[The eslint plugin for import statements](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import) may have some of what you are looking for. Specifically [no-relative-parent-imports](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-relative-parent-imports.md) which allows you to error on any relative parent lookup (`../`).

Comment: Interesting. Definitely similar to what I have in mind. I'll take a look.